# How to add all AD Users to a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to write an application to manage AD users but am having some issues. The code I wrote only adds some of the users in the AD to the ComboBox but not all. There is no relation to the people being added. Any help is appreciated.

```
private void TestNames(){
        DirectoryEntry RootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=xxxxx,DC=com");
        DirectorySearcher ADSearch = new DirectorySearcher(RootDSE);

        foreach (SearchResult ADSearchResult in ADSearch.FindAll()){
            if (ADSearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["employeeID"].Value != null){
                name.Items.Add(ADSearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["displayName"].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like this to add all AD users to the ComboBox but right now it only adds a few unrelated users

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Just for clarification: What does this have to do with WPF? It seems to be an AD problem. Can you give some more details, for example expected output and actual output?

Comment: I don't know how your AD is structured, but you might need to set `ADSearch.SizeLimit` to something higher or maybe you need to change `ADSearch.SearchScope`. Look at the different properties for [DirectorySearcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher?view=netframework-4.8) because it seems like that's where your problem is.